Should I use spring.profiles.active or SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE in elastic beanstalk env variables?
It seems that everywhere on the web if you search for how to set the spring profile in elastic beanstalk, the answers all say to set the SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE but I found one person saying to set spring.profiles.active instead. I'm confused as there's almost no documentation anywhere in AWS or Spring Boot around this. Is one the old answer and another the new answer? Was it a change in Spring Boot version or a change in AWS elastic beanstalk?
I tried both and ultimately spring.profiles.active seems to work but this is at odds with all the documentation on the internet. Why is there no documentation on this? Is there a situation in which SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE is still the right answer in 2024?
